# ¿Como Llamar una funcion entre componentes de angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, component

Antes que nada hablemos de lo implementado, estoy utilizando Angular en su versión 1.6, y estoy comenzando a implementar el uso de los componentes. estoy creando un `single page aplication` y estoy utilizando componentes para dividir las tareas. también utilizo funciones auto ejecutables de `javascript` para construir los controladores.

El problema lo tengo cuando necesito llamar una función en el controlador del componente desde el controlador principal. se que se puede usar los **bindings** para enviar parámetros, pero no se como disparar una función anidada desde el controlador principal, ya que este no es consiente de las funciones del controlador del componente.

**Configuración del componente:**

```js
(function(angular,AppName){     
    var app = angular.module(AppName); 
    app.component("informacionInicialComponent", {   
        controller : "informacionInicialController",
        bindings:{
            ordenServicio : "=",
            abrirStep : "="
        },
        templateUrl : "./rel/views/templates/informacion_inicial.html",  
    });

}(window.angular, window.AppName));
```

Se que se puede llamar desde el controlador del componente los objetos enviados por el **bindings** usando el `this` para esto implemento una variable `$scope.x = this` de la siguiente forma:

```js
(function(angular, AppName){
    var app = angular.module(AppName); 
    var controller = function($scope){

        $scope.indexController = this;
        

        $scope.funcionAllamar = function(){
            console.log("ejecutando funcion desde controlador principal");
        }
    };

    controller.$inject = ["$scope"];
    app.controller("informacionInicialController", controller);

}(window.angular, window.AppName));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Quiero llamar la función en este caso llamada **funcionALlamar** desde el controlador principal, pero no se como hacerlo, e escuchado algo sobre el uso de `triggers` pero no se como implementarlos, les agradecería cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, por favor no es una buena practica colocar el código dentro de una imagen. Si Ud. puede edite si pregunta y coloque el código dentro de la etiquetas correspondiente.